# Confusions regarding InetAdress.getByName()

Tags: java, network-programming

I am trying to write a class which would print the actual hostname of the IP address supplied as an argument to the InetAddress.getByName(). But everytime I run the program the IP address gets printed on the console rather than the hostname.

> This is my output:= 
>   208.73.211.249

What would I have to do to print it correctly?

```
import java.net.*;

public class Inet1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        InetAddress ia=null;
        ia=InetAddress.getByName("74.125.236.50");
        System.out.print(ia.getHostName());

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the javadoc for this method explicitly says that this returns an IP address for a hostname; if you submit an IP address it will return it...

Comment: So what do I have to do for getting the hostname for the requested IP address?

Comment: The most reliable way is to use a DNS library -- provided you use DNS for name resolution, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName("74.125.236.50");


String hostname = inetAddr.getHostName(); // Get the host name
```

Comment: if the IP address is within your network it should print the Host name, otherwise it will print the IP Address itself.

Comment: So what do I have to do for obtaining the hostname. Say I am trying to find the host name for this address 208.73.211.249.

Comment: Most of the time (public) IP <-> host name has a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure if the hostname will work outside the network, you can refer this link which has a similar discussion (http://serverfault.com/questions/254402/how-do-i-find-out-my-host-name-and-ip-address-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying system configuration might not allow you to access the host name. Then there's nothing you can do on Java level.

Have you tried

```
System.out.println(ia.getCanonicalHostName());
```

?

Comment: This won't resolve an IP address, only show the FQDN of the local machine